# problem /w merging file and next function in line will have that file as parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm currently having some problem with two function that isn't executing the way i wanted.

```
app.post('/', async (req, res) => {

    // This function will take pcs.txt and pcequp.txt and make pcs_pcequip.txt
    await filefunction.mergeFiles('./../server/data/text1.txt','./../server/data/text2.txt',"./data/text3.txt"); 

    // Parse the data file text3.txt into JSON.
    await JSONParser.StartJSONParser();
}
```

mergeFiles will take two files and merge them into one file. This file is then the basis for StartJSONParser (). But I do not succeed in making mergeFiles complete before StartJSONParser starts.

> mergeFiles function

```
    static mergeFiles(file1,file2, destination){
    concat([file1,file2], destination, function(err) {
        if(err) throw err
    });
}
```

> StartJSONParser

```
   static StartJSONParser() {
    this.readFile("./data/text3.txt", "./data/text3.json", new RegExp("[^\\n\\r\\t ]+", 'g'));

   }

   static readFile(inData, outData, regex) {

   }
```

Is there anyone who has tips on how to think, for the files to become merged before the next function starts??

Answer (score 1):

You're calling await on `mergeFiles` but that isn't a promise so it won't 'wait'.

You could try changing `mergeFiles` to something like this:

```
static mergeFiles(file1,file2, destination){ 
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    concat([file1,file2], destination, function(err) {
        if(err) throw err
        resolve();
    });
  })
}
```

I think this should work, I've created this example code snippet that works so maybe you can use that to help you

```
async function init() {
    function mergeFiles() {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                console.log('mergeFiles');
                resolve();
            }, 5000);
        })
    }

    await mergeFiles();
    console.log('after')
}
```

Though it does depend on what `concat` is, if this function is async then its likely all you need to do is return the concat function so that await works with it.

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using https://www.npmjs.com/package/concat package to concat files it returns a promise.

SO rather you can just do this:

```
static mergeFiles(file1,file2, destination){
    return concat([file1,file2], destination);
}
```

This way your function would return a promise that you can await the way you are doing.